# Issue with starting Chrome WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an issue with starting a Chrome driver during initialization in a C# class when I try to start my application (NET Core 3.1) on a Windows Server 2012 R2 - it cannot start the driver directly and throws an exception (I used a remote debugger to find out):

> Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:{RandomPort}/

Besides this, when I start the driver from the application's directory on the server by PowerShell, it starts correctly:

```
C:\SomePath> .\chromedriver.exe
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.88 (89e2380a3e36c3464b5dd1302349b1382549290d-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#1761}) on port {RandomPort}
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

But when I start the application on my local machine, it launches the driver and everything works fine.
Due to employer's security policy, I cannot install Chrome on the server so initialization happens as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\chrome\\chrome.exe";
WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

On my local machine, right after the `WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);` I can use Selenium's APIs. But on the server it throws the exception.

I tried to launch the application on a different server with the same OS and it does not throw an exception. But it does not launch Chrome either - the chrome.exe processes are shown in the task manager, but the browser does not open and everything chashes when the app tries to interact with Selenium's APIs. Chrome's version fits with the driver's version. Do you have any idea why the exception ossurs?

**UPD1:**
If lauch chromedriver.exe from a command prompt and define allowed IPs, it allows to interact with it and opens the browser's window even from remote PCs:

```
c:\SomePath>chromedriver.exe --allowed-ips="{myLocalIP}"
Starting ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}) on port 9515
Remote connections are allowed by an allowlist (myLocalIP).
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

For a remote connection to the driver I tried the following code, but it forces me to change the other code since IWebDriver cannot be casted to ChromeDriver type:

```
DriverOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
IWebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://{remoteServerIP}:9515"), options);
wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("{someInternalUrl}");
```

The problem of direct initialization from the code is relevant on servers but does not reproduce on local machines.

**UPD2:**
I also tried to provide different accounts with different privileges to use in the application pool but it did not help - chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe processes were just launched under different accounts.

Comment: see port use is blocked by firewall settings

Comment: Your company is probably blocking almost every port, except for the common web ports (80 and 443). You might need to work with your server admins to open a port accessible only to localhost connections, and then start ChromeDriver on that port.

Comment: Hi @Mike, Please check [this articles](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver), when using the ChromeDriver, it requires installing the Chrome browser in the default location for each system, you have to install the Chrome browser on the server.

Comment: @Greg Burdhardt, I can use any port. There is IIS Manager on the server and firewall allows to use any port.

Comment: @ZhiLv, I've installed Chrome on the server and it did not help much - chromedriver.exe and chrome.exe are shown in task manager, but browser's window does not open. Nonetheless, when I start chromedriver from a command prompt with defining allowed IPs, it opens browser's window after connection from a remote PC and allows to use it. Chromedriver just does not start directly from my code on the server but starts locally.